# Automatically display multiple playlists from SoundCloud

Tags: php, javascript, soundcloud

I am creating a music website for a client, previously I had a backend system that would manage the music section, however the client wishes to have all the music pulled from sound cloud. Currently there's 1 album, but a second is planned to be released shortly.

My question is how to have the website automatically pull the separate album (or playlist) songs through php and display each album in it's own shell. For example, the website would have for each album the artwork and then the list of playable songs.

I've looked at the documentation and across google but there doesn't seem to be any way to have a website auto-generate each album. Does anyone know how to achieve this (preferably though php) or know where I can find out?

Comment: Haven't tried anything, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to pull all the sets.

Comment: I also once started Soundcloud integration but their documentation is too bad that I drop out and made my new own player.If you got any good documentation please let me know too :)